# How to calculate the Fourier transform of a two-dimensional Sinc function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

As shown below, how to calculate the Fourier transform of a two-dimensional *Sinc* function?

[image]

where b is a positive number and corresponds to the width of the *Sinc* function.

I guess the result might be in the form of 
[image]

but I donot know how to prove this.
Who can help me prove this?
Any help or comment are highly appreciated.

Comment: This integral diverges, you need the Fourier transform of distributions. Also $\mathcal{F}[g(M t)](\omega) = \frac{1}{|\det M|}\mathcal{F}[g( t)](M^{-T}\omega)$ for any inversible matrix $M$, so it reduces to the Fourier transform of $sinc(b \omega_1)$ which is $C 1_{|t_1| < 1/2} \delta(t_2)$

Comment: @user1952009, Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: @user1952009,  it is a good idea to reduce sinc(b(w1-w2)) to sinc(bw1) , but how to do this specifically? Could you please show more details?  What is C1 here?

Comment: Look at the distribution $S(t_1,t_2) = \delta(t_2) 1_{|t_1| < 1/2}$. What is its Fourier transform ? And what is the Fourier transform of $S(t_1+t_2, t_1-t_2)$ ?